# CSS Hidden First Child

Tags: html, css

I have an un-editable HTML, which cannot change anything.

I need to hide the first checkbox and the second one will show.  It is done in CSS, but somehow it doesn't work as expected.
Here is its [LIVE](https://jsfiddle.net/sa3k71by/) sample.

Please help.

```css
.treeview-container .treeview-item:first-child .form-check label input[type="checkbox"] {   
                visibility: hidden;      
     }
```

```html
    <div class="treeview-container">
        <div class="treeview-item">
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                  <input type="checkbox" />First Box
               </label>
            </div>
            <div class="treeview-item">
                <div class="form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                      <input type="checkbox" />Second Box
                   </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.treeview-item:first-child` is targetting **both** of the checkboxes' respective `.form-check` containers (as they are both the first child of their parent `.treeview-item`).

This is perhaps a little counter-intuitive, as you may expect the **[`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child)** pseudo-selector to only target the **very** first occurence of a child of `.treeview-item`. This is not the case, as the `:first-child` selector actually targets the first child of **each** of the `.treeview-item` parents.

In order to correct this, you can simply use two **[child combinator selectors (`>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)** to ensure that `.treeview-item` is a direct child of `.treeview-container`, and `.form-check` is a direct child of that `.treeview-item`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.treeview-container > .treeview-item > .form-check label input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="treeview-container">
  <div class="treeview-item">
    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input type="checkbox" />First Box
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="treeview-item">
      <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input type="checkbox" />Second Box
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, Obsidian for help with a clear explanation!  It works.

Comment: Probably should have `.form-check .form-check-label.label` instead of `.form-check label`

Comment: That would certainly also be valid; it depends how much [**specificity**](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) you want to apply. Simply specifying the element is enough for this example :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.treeview-item:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to add some explanation. Code-only answers are discouraged and may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ID and add it to any elements you want hidden. However this only hides the element. If you do not want the user to be able to change the checkbox you may want to remove that input type all together.

```css
.treeview-container .treeview-item:first-child .form-check label input[type="checkbox"] {   
                visibility: hidden;      
     }
     
#hideMe {
 display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="treeview-container">
        <div class="treeview-item">
            <div class="form-check">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                  <input type="checkbox" id = "hideMe"/>First Box
               </label>
            </div>
            <div class="treeview-item">
                <div class="form-check">
                  <label class="form-check-label">
                      <input type="checkbox" />Second Box
                   </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Probably should have `.form-check .form-check-label.label` instead of `.form-check label`

Answer (score 0):

Using child combinator (>) in between two selectors will select a direct child of the parent. Currently, your code is selecting both inputs as you are just checking for decendents ..ie if the `input` has an ancestor as `.treeview-container` or not. 
So using two consecutive child combinator will help you get expected result. 
Code below.

```
.treeview-container > div > .form-check label input[type="checkbox"] {   
            visibility: hidden;      
 }
```

Comment: Probably should have `.form-check .form-check-label.label` instead of `.form-check label`